# ARM how to correctly read an instruction encoding

Tags: c, encoding, disassembly, opcode

I am trying to read an instruction based on the ARM instruction set reference manual but so far i am unable to find a valid encoding for the second encoding after the base encoding (data processing and miscellaneous instructions)

I have tried re interperating the encoding and interperating the encoding line by line but the second encoding is always invalid

```
function = 0x2d02dd
bit length: 32
lines to read = 4 (1 line == 32 bits read)
buffer = 0x2d02dd
b0 80 b5 6f 
10110000 10000000 10110101 01101111 
bufferb = 0x2d02dd
bit = 0x2d02dd
encoding = 0x2d02dd
cond = 1011
Mnemonic extention: LT
Meaning (integer): Signed less than
Meaning (floating point){a}: Less than, or unordered
a. Unordered means at least one NaN operand
Condition flags: N != V
op1 = 000
unspecified1 = 01000000010110101011
op = 0
unspecified2 = 1111
encoding group: data processing and miscellaneous instructions
bitc = 4
encoding = 0x2d02e1
    cond = 0100
    zero1 = 0
    zero2 = 1
    op = 1
    op1 = 00111
    unspecified1 = 101101100001
    op2 = 0011
    unspecified2 = 1010
    encoding group: b0 80 b5 6f
function = 0x2d02dd
i*length = 0
buffer = 0x2d02e1
46 7b 61 3a 
01000110 01111011 01100001 00111010 
bufferb = 0x2d02e1
bit = 0x2d02e1
encoding = 0x2d02e1
cond = 0100
Mnemonic extention: MI
Meaning (integer): Minus, negative
Meaning (floating point){a}: Less than
a. Unordered means at least one NaN operand
Condition flags: N == 1
op1 = 011
unspecified1 = 00111101101100001001
op = 1
unspecified2 = 1010
encoding group: 46 7b 61 3a 
function = 0x2d02dd
i*length = 4
buffer = 0x2d02e5
61 f9 60 00 
01100001 11111001 01100000 00000000 
bufferb = 0x2d02e5
bit = 0x2d02e5
encoding = 0x2d02e5
cond = 0110
Mnemonic extention: VS
Meaning (integer): Overflow
Meaning (floating point){a}: Unordered
a. Unordered means at least one NaN operand
Condition flags: V == 1
op1 = 000
unspecified1 = 11111100101100000000
op = 0
unspecified2 = 0000
encoding group: data processing and miscellaneous instructions
bitc = 4
encoding = 0x2d02e9
    cond = 0010
    zero1 = 0
    zero2 = 0
    op = 0
    op1 = 11011
    unspecified1 = 100001100000
    op2 = 0000
    unspecified2 = 0111
    encoding group: 61 f9 60 00 
function = 0x2d02dd
i*length = 8
buffer = 0x2d02e9
21 b8 60 07 
00100001 10111000 01100000 00000111 
bufferb = 0x2d02e9
bit = 0x2d02e9
encoding = 0x2d02e9
cond = 0010
Mnemonic extention: CS{b}
Meaning (integer): Carry Set
Meaning (floating point){a}: Greater than, equal, or unordered
a. Unordered means at least one NaN operand
Condition flags: C == 1
b. HS (unsigned higher or same) is a synonym for CS
op1 = 000
unspecified1 = 11011100001100000000
op = 0
unspecified2 = 0111
encoding group: data processing and miscellaneous instructions
bitc = 4
encoding = 0x2d02ed
    cond = 1111
    zero1 = 0
    zero2 = 0
    op = 0
    op1 = 10000
    unspecified1 = 100000000000
    op2 = 0000
    unspecified2 = 0001
    encoding group: miscellaneous instructions
21 b8 60 07 
function = 0x2d02dd
i*length = 12
function = 0x2d02dd
```

https://bpaste.net/show/5bb012932588

Comment: this is an invalid/implementation defined way to use unions and should be avoided.  you should also avoid bitfields.  what problem are you having with shifting and masking yourself (rather than hoping the compiler will do it for you)?

Comment: further inspection beyond the glaring use of a union at the top, it looks like you are doing a whole lot of excess work for what I am guessing is a simple task, disassembling arm instructions (or thumb)?   note if you choose to support thumb2 extensions then you have to deal with variable length which means disassemble in execution order not linearly through memory.   but you first need to pick an instruction set, take a simple example.   I dont see any instructions or machine code to show what it is you are really trying to do...

Comment: please add a few instructions, hex or binary or both, and non-programmatically show what your expected output is and/or what you expect to extract from those instructions.

Comment: or is this not about ripping the instruction apart at all but more about how to store each piece as you pull it apart (as the title question implies?)

Comment: Updated question